# Understanding lc3 program

Tags: assembly, lc3

Im trying to understand this code . I know he suppose to print "ABCDEFG" or "ABCDFGH" (according to 2 options) but i cannot understand why it heppens.

My problem is that why in x3001 R1=R0+0 While R0 is not given in front and the program workd.
Thanks.

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA R1, TESTOUT
ADD R1, R0, #0
BACK_1 LDR R0, R1, #0
BRz NEXT_1
TRAP x21
ADD R1, R1, #1
BRnzp BACK_1
NEXT_1 LEA R1, TESTOUT
BACK_2 LDR R0, R1, #0
BRz NEXT_2
JSR SUB_1
ADD R1, R1, #1
BRnzp BACK_2
NEXT_2 TRAP x25
SUB_1 ADD R0, R0, #5 / ADD R0, R0, #3
K LDI R2, DSR
  BRzp K
STI R0, DDR
RET
DSR .FILL xF3FC
DDR .FILL xF3FF
TESTOUT .STRINGZ "ABC"
.END
```

Comment: Yeah that instruction seems nonsensical. If `R0` is known to be zero, it's pointless to add it. If it's not known, then what the hell is it adding? Especially since we want `R1` to point to the start of the string. Note the second version does not add it.

Comment: exactly. I am practicing to my exam and this is one of the exams with solution that they gave us, but i can not figure out this solution.